# Java PrintWriter Print character not displaying the last character

Tags: java, servlets

I really not getting where the problem is.
I wanted to print the characters to a text file and im uisng printWriter to do the same.
if the file has a ";", i want to replace it with a new line and this is what im doing,

```
public static void downloadFile_txt(String sourceFilePathName, String contentType, String destFileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
 {
     File file = new File(sourceFilePathName);
     //FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
     FileReader fileIn = new FileReader(file); 
     long fileLen = file.length();
     response.setContentType(contentType);
     response.setContentLength((int)fileLen);

     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.valueOf((new  StringBuffer("attachment;")).append("filename=").append(destFileName)));

     PrintWriter pw =  response.getWriter();


     // Loop to read and write bytes.
     int c=-1;      
     while ((c = fileIn.read()) != -1)
     {

         if(c!=59)
         {
              pw.print((char)c);
         }
         else
         {
              pw.println();
         }
     }
     pw.flush();
     pw=null;        
     fileIn.close();        
}
```

But my file is priting everything except for the last character.
Eg.input =

```
:00004000,FFAD,2 Byte Ch;
:0000FFBD,FFBE,2 Byte Ch;
:0000FFBF,FFFF,2 Byte Ch;
```

output which im getting

```
:00004000,FFAD,2 Byte Ch
:0000FFBD,FFBE,2 Byte Ch
:0000FFBF,FFFF,2 Byte C
```

the last "h" is not getting printed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `pw.flush();` might help you.

```
public class FlushPrintWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        FileReader fileIn = new FileReader("in.txt");
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
        int c;        
        while ((c = fileIn.read()) != -1) {
            if(c!=59) {
               pw.print((char)c);
            } else {
               pw.println();
            }
        }
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

outputs

```
:00004000,FFAD,2 Byte Ch

:0000FFBD,FFBE,2 Byte Ch

:0000FFBF,FFFF,2 Byte Ch
```

as expected.

(Don't handle your `IOException`s like this - and close your readers and writers - this is for demonstration only!)

---

**edit:** now your code doesn't even compile (two vars called `fileIn`?)!

Even when run through the servlet code you're now mentioning, I can't reproduce your problem, and the output is as you would expect. So this is me giving up. I'm starting to suspect either the final `;` isn't in your source file, or there is yet more processing your app is doing that you're not showing us.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for providng example. It prints the same if im displaying it in my console but if im writing it to a text file the last character is missing

Comment: @mee - nope, still can't reproduce your problem! See updated example.

Comment: Thank you so much...please find the edited code which im using..it still prints the same :(

Comment: sorry for the confusion, im using fileReader. Thank u for the help. i will try to find out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try flush() or close() your print writer.

And may be it is better to read line by line, replacing characters using String.replace()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ya im using pw.flush() and pw=null soon after the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Run the while loop upto file size

```
 int fileSize=file.length();
 while(fileSize>0)
 {
    //do your task of reading charcter and printing it or whatever you want
    fileSize--;
 }
```